# Grails g:javascript tag with query string generates error

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-2.0

When I create a tag `<g:javascript src="highcharts/highcharts.js?v=255" />` i get the error:

```
I can't work out the type of /tools/js/highcharts/highcharts.js?v=205 with type [text/javascript]. Please check the URL, resource definition or specify [type] attribute
```

The docs say that g:javascript doesn't have a type attribute and after looking through the grails source I found that it's using FileNameUtils.getExtension() to determine the type of resource. Since that just does a lastIndexOf('.') and returns the right side of that, it obviously won't be found.  In this case we don't really need to add the v=255 so I can remove it for now however I'd still like to be able to do so in the future.  What are my options here?

Grails version is 2.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using the HTML tag?

```
<script src="highcharts/highcharts.js?v=255 type="text/javascript"/>
```

Comment: the whole point of the g:javascript tag is that it's tied in to the resources plugin from grails and manages other lifecycle events for you, similar to the rails asset pipeline

Comment: I ended up doing this even though I shouldn't have to so you get the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is deal with versioning javascript includes so you can set the cache high and change the number as needed you should look at the [grails cached resources plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cached-resources).

Personally I think you would want to make highcharts.js part of a module for the resources plugin to deal with for you. It will take care of versioning and minification etc as you let it. The [quick start](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/) should give you enough to get going.